# Javascript .className not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use this bit of js to change the class of links referring to the current URL. It seems to work halfway, but the `.className` bit won't work. If I use `a[i].innerHTML = 'activelink'` for example, it does change the `innerHTML`. Firebug reports no errors.

```
window.onload = activateCurrentLink;

function activateCurrentLink(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        if(a[i].href == window.location.href.split("#")[0])
            a[i].className += 'activelink';
}
```

I have to admit this is mostly copypasta, as my js knowledge is very, very limited. Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you logged `a[i].href` and `window.location.href.split("#")[0]` to see if they actually match?

Comment: FYI, `a[i].classList.add("activelink")` is much nicer. You can patch it into IE8/9 if desired.

Comment: Ok, I made a big mistake. I was checking in the browser's source code view if the class was added. But I couldn't see it. While looking at the rendered page, it does work. I learned something about Javascript... What do we do with this question now? Embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

You forget the space symbol which is necessary when adding an additional class to an element

```
a[i].className += ' activelink';
```

Comment: Hmmm. I tried it but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @jimmy: Your `a[i].href == window.location.href.split("#")[0]` won't work because `a[i].href` will give you a fully qualified domain. Try `a[i].hash === window.location.hash` if you want to compare hashes.

Comment: Or just do `document.querySelectorAll("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']")`

Comment: @sixfingeredman Your first suggestion had no effect, and I'm not sure how to use the second one. Could you please show me in context?

Comment: @jimmy: Your `.innerHTML` test actually worked inside the `if()` statement? Or did you do it before the `if`?